# Can't copy image URL on Google Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, images, copy-paste, hyperlinks

I have a Samsung Galaxy Avant with Android 4.4.2, and up until a couple of days ago, I've been able to copy image addresses with Google Chrome, but now I don't see the option anymore.

[image]

I've tried it with several different websites that I have copied from before. I am thinking it's part of an update although I didn't ever see an update notification. It's really annoying because I used that feature a lot.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: It's removed along with some other options due to this issue: https://crbug.com/483685. I filed [this](https://crbug.com/583741) issue regarding the "open image in new tab" option but it was closed as "WontFix".

Answer (score 2):

For those looking here in 2023 and onward, this option has been moved and is difficult to find, but is still present. When viewing a picture in Google Chrome, first long-press to get the menu shown in the original screenshot and choose **Share image**.

When you get the Sharing dialog, there should be a "broken link" icon in the top right, and tapping it will (1) include the link if you decide to share the photo itself and (2) enable a "Copy link" option in the share menu.

Screenshots to visualize:

[image: Long-press context menu]
[image: Include link button]
[image: Copy link button]